Quasi-geodesics in Alexandrov spaces
I am trying to understand the notion of quasi-geodesic in Alexandrov space with curvature bounded below following the Perelman-Petrunin paper. I have two questions:

Is it true that the shortest geodesic is a quasi-geodesic?
Given a continuous path which is a union of two shortest geodesics with a common end. Under what conditions it is a quasi-geodesic?

